# Sybase ASE 16 upgrade Test Approach

Tags: database, testing, sybase, load-testing, sap-ase

I will be working as QA on a projects which is upgrading Sybase ASE to version 16.
I have not worked on RDBMS system upgrade projects before. I need assistance in drafting a Test strategy. Could anyone please provide me guidance on
- What are the Steps involved in upgrading Sybase ASE version
- From System test point of view what sorts of test should we be running (We are already running regression on the applications which are connected to the DBs but apart from that what else should we be validating?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you also need to be checking post-upgrade performance, i.e. run some set of load tests against per-upgrade configuration and re-run the same set after the upgrade to ensure that upgrade didn't cause performance degradation.

You can use i.e. [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), it can execute arbitrary SQL queries in multithreaded manner via [JTDS JDBC Driver](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jtds/). See [The Real Secret to Building a Database Test Plan With JMeter](https://blazemeter.com/blog/secret-building-database-test-plan-with-jmeter) article for details.

Comment: Thank you so much for your guidance apart yes load testing is being done. Do we have to do anything is functional testing?

Comment: From SQL side you can compare pre and post upgrade schemas to ensure that all indices, constraints, etc. are in place. Also there would be good to run a couple of end-to-end tests from application perspective, some baseline sanity check to ensure that major functionality still works

Comment: The steps for an ASE upgrade should be the same as any RDBMS upgrade i.e. functional and performance tests of key processes/ screens/components, end to end testing of all critical batch or similar processes etc. Bear in mind that things like null testing has been known to change between Sybase versions so may need to be considered depending upon your prior ASE version (which you have not mentioned). This would for example be extremely important if you are migrating from 12.5.x or 15.0.

You can also have differences in behavior for JDBC/ODBC versions and drivers.